# Searching by category in Django and not by product

Tags: django, search, categories

I have created a search bar which searches based on product name. I would now like to change this to search by category but I am finding it difficult. 
Here is my URLs file:
'''

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.marketplaceHome, name='marketplace-home'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.Contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<product_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.productPage, name='product_detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.marketplaceHome, name='products_by_category'),
    url('^cart$', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
    url(r'^cart/add/(?P<product_id>[-\w]+)/$', views.add_cart, name='add_cart'),
    url(r'^cart/remove/(?P<product_id>[-\w]+)/$', views.cart_remove, name='cart_remove'),
    url(r'^cart/remove_product/(?P<product_id>[-\w]+)/$', views.cart_remove_product, name='cart_remove_product'),
         ]
```

'''
views.py
'''

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import Category, Product, Cart, CartItem
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from . import forms

# Create your views here.

def marketplaceHome(request, category_slug=None):
    category_page = None
    products = None
    if category_slug !=None:
        category_page = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = Product.objects.filter(category=category_page, available=True)
    else:
        products = Product.objects.all().filter(available=True)
    return render(request, 'marketplacehome.html', {'category': category_page, 'products': products})


def productPage(request, category_slug, product_slug):
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(category__slug=category_slug, slug=product_slug)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    return render(request, 'product.html', {'product': product})


def search(request):
    products = Product.objects.filter(name__contains=request.GET['name'])
    return render(request, 'marketplacehome.html', { 'products': products})
```

'''
template.html
'''

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <form class="form-inline" action="{% url 'search' %}", method="GET">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Location" aria-label="Search" name="query">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

'''
models.py
'''

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('products_by_category', args=[self.slug])


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="product", blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    single_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    twelve_lesson_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'products'

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('product_detail', args=[self.category.slug, self.slug])

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
```

'''

This structure successfully returned the products which were searched by name but when i changed it to categories it did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can search with:

```
def search(request):
    products = Product.objects.filter(
        category__name__icontains=request.GET['name']
    )
    return render(request, 'marketplacehome.html', { 'products': products})
```

So here you search if the `name` of the `category` of the object contains the given `request.GET['name']`.

You can use `__icontains` to match case *in*-senstive, or `__contains` to match case sensitive.

You can combine the two with `Q`-objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def search(request):
    products = Product.objects.filter(
        Q(category__name__icontains=request.GET['name']) |
        Q(name__icontains=request.GET['name'])
    )
    return render(request, 'marketplacehome.html', { 'products': products})
```

This will return `Product`s where the `name` of the `Product` matches, or the `name` of its `category` matches.